# onBackPressed takes user back to main activity

Tags: android

Below I have a method that cancel my asynctask and `ProgressDialog`.  The code works well but when you press the back button it stops everything as its suppose too but it will just leave the user staring at a unpopulated listview.  So the idea here is that when the user clicks the back button it stops the asynctask and `ProgressDialog` and instead of just leaving them looking at a unpopulated listview I want it to also take them back to the main activity as well.  Can anybody help me to make this possible?

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() 
{              
    /** If user Pressed BackButton While Running Asynctask
        this will close the ASynctask.
     */
    if (mTask != null && mTask.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)
    {
        mTask.cancel(true);
    }          
    super.onBackPressed();
}


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


/** If Activity is Destroyed While Running Asynctask
        this will close the ASynctask.   */

 if (mTask != null && mTask.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)
 {
    mTask.cancel(true);
  }  

    super.onDestroy();

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


 if (pDialog != null)
 {
     if(pDialog.isShowing())
     {
         pDialog.dismiss();
     }
        super.onPause();

  }  

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `finish();` after `super.onBackPressed();`

Comment: it is still not taking me back to the main activity

Comment: You need to debug and see when you reach the finish() if the dialogue is still open. If so you need to dismiss it before.

Comment: I found that just my progress dialog is being dismissed but the asynctask still executes

Answer (score 0):

Simply calling `mTask.cancel(true);` won't immediately cancel your `AsyncTask`. You need to periodically call `isCancelled()` in `doInBackground(...)` - if the result is `true` you need to return from `doInBackground(...)`.

In this case, `onPostExecute(...)` will not be called and instead `onCancelled()` will be called and you can call `finish()` to terminate the `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

use this :
getActivity = for fragment, for activity use ActivityName.this

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            finishActivity(false);
```